AWS ECS with Django + Python + Alpine produce Segmentation Fault
we are currently having trouble with Alpine Linux, since the Update to Version>=17.
It seems that since alpine17 the openssl library in alpine was updated to openssl3.
The problem is that we have our Django application, which is built via Dockerfile does not work with alpine>=17 on AWS ECS anymore.
We are installing additional dependencies, such as: gcc, build-base, bind-tools, mysql-client, mariadb-dev, postgresql14-client, xmlsec, git, util-linux, curl-dev, openssl, libffi-dev
Then we tested different images, e.g. python3.11.9-alpine3.20,python3.11.9-alpine3.18, python3.11.3-alpine3.17, python3.12.4-alpine3.18 etc.
It worked with python3.11.3-alpine3.16.
The strange thing is: it does actually work if we built and deploy the django application locally via docker-compose and use python3.11.9-alpine3.20 for example.
But if we build the containers (nginx, django, worker, beat) via git-ci and deploy them on AWS ECS with Fargate or EC2 as launch types, it gives those errors.
The log in the django-container simply states: !!! uWSGI process 35 got Segmentation Fault !!!
Then the worker process is terminated. This error arises everytime a connection to django, to nginx or to the loadbalancer is done.
Locally we also see the output: 485BA4DBE17F0000:error:0A000126:SSL routines:ssl3_read_n:unexpected eof while reading:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:322: ssl_client: SSL_connect
We assume that there might be some incompatibility between the new openssl3, the openssl from AWS and probably django. Because the local deployment with docker-compose actually works.
Did somebody encounter a similar problem or has an idea how to fix that?

One of the things that makes the Alpine base image small is an alternate version of the core C share library.  If you're having weird library-dependency issues, does switching to the Debian-based Python image help?  For Python in particular, the Debian-based image also might be able to avoid needing the C toolchain (gcc &c.) for a smaller/simpler image.

@DavidMaze Yes we thought about a change to debian (e.g. slim-bookworm) but our ideal solution would still include alpine, as we are pretty happy with the image in general.

@MarkB We also use an up-to-date cryptography library (42.0.7) in our python requirements for django
